# Bug in rendering paper-button

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design, paper-elements

I have two identical paper-buttons except for there ids:

```dart
<paper-button raisedButton
  id='rendered'
  label='patient'
  on-click='{{clickHandler}}'></paper-button>

<paper-button raisedButton
  id='no-render'
  label='patient'
  on-click='{{clickHandler}}'>
</paper-button>
```

The first button renders with its text label, the second renders without the text label. The only difference is the closing  tag. I would expect the the second button should be rendered like the first, but it does not. Is this a bug?

Another observation is that the button's label always defaults to upper-case. Can this be changed?

I am using polymer v 0.12.0-dev and Dart Editor version 1.6.0.dev_03_00 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.6.0-dev.3.0.

Comment: Please add </paper-button> in the fifth line (new line) of the second button matching the opening tag. After adding the question I could not edit it.

Comment: The indentation was one character short. I thought questions are always editable. I'll take a look why this was disabled for you.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a reason why you wouldn't be able to edit your question. Do you get some kind of message or is the `edit` link disabled or is it not even visible?

Comment: @st_clair_clarke If you follow [this edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24720197/edit) are you able to edit your question?

Comment: @st_clair_clarke: You can **always** edit your question. Do you mean you had some sort of error when you tried?

Comment: The edit link was NOT clickable. Under normal circumstances when I point to it, the cursor changed to a hand pointer. All I had was the typical arrow-head pointer. There was not error.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke what about the other buttons [share], [close], [flag]. Do they seem inactive too, or is this only for the \[edit\] button? When I mouse-over the links are shown inverse too (white text on dark-grey background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second button is rendered differently (without the caption) and I get the error message

```
Using textContent to label the button is deprecated. Use the "label" property instead
```

Obviously the `<paper-button>` is designed to recognize if someone adds childnodes, which seems not to be supported.
The line break between opening and closing tag creates a `TextNode` children which changes the behavior of the button.

I guess there was a good intention in the way the button is designed but the result might cause more confustion than help.

I created a bug report https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/issues/12

Comment: Thanks. I was getting the same error message but it went away when I placed the </paper-button> tag as in option 1 above. I agree it should be corrected as many of us indent code for easy readability.

Comment: Yes, usually there is no difference in the behavior when there are only white-space characters between opening and closing tag.

Comment: The stack trace  was not very helpful in pinpointing the problem either. I still receive the error even though I corrected the perceived problem. I am currently investigating if other paper-element component behave similarly.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. I had a look at the `paper-button` JavaScript source and there it was explicitely coded. If <content> contains text this text is used as label and the error message is printed. There might be some other element where this was done in a similar way but it's not a generic problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will still try to find the issue because I have the trace which is unexpected.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/blob/master/paper-button.html#L134

Comment: I did see that Gunter, Thanks. I found the reason for the stack trace - another button. Every paper-component that has <*-button> in its component has the problem.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that stack trace.

Comment: When Dart paper-elements were generated this check for white-spaces wasn't yet included in JS paper-button. This will be fixed in Dart paper-button automatically with the next release.